# Drupal Commerce checkout for CiviEvent registration?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, drupal-rules

Has anyone used Drupal Commerce's checkout process to process CiviEvent payments instead of the core CiviCRM payment processor?

I have seen a number of discussions about integrating CiviCRM with Drupal Commerce, but no concrete evidence that someone has successfully created a CiviEvent registration page that processes payments through the Drupal Commerce checkout engine.

I did a thought experiment and it seems possible to create a Drupal Webform that could tie together webform CiviEvent integration and webform Commerce integration. These modules exist, so it should be possible:

CiviCRM Webform Integration

Commerce CiviCRM Rules (on eileenmcnaughton GitHub https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/commerce_civicrm_rules)

Additionally there is Webform Commerce integration, if needed.

Has anyone ever used this type of Frankenstein event registration setup?

Comment: The discussions I have seen to date about CiviEvent and Commerce integration were based on idea of creating a Commerce Product that is linked to the Event, and it is the Product that is added to the Cart, and upon submission the integration would result in the Participant record being created. I don't recall suggestions of tieing the Event 'page' in to Commerce.